# Conversion of bytearray from string form, back to bytearray in Python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, type-conversion

I have a string representation of a bytearray:

```
'\x12>\x1e\xf3\xda\xae\xb2>\x8c\xb7k\x8aN2CZX\xe3\xe4\r\x7f\xc6\x80\xba\x13\x13\x90\xa4\x....'
```

I want to know how to convert it back into a bytearray.

Request: I expect to learn earnestly, so please refrain from sarcasm.

Comment: You mean like passing it to the `bytearray` function?

Comment: Absolutely! Like that. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = '\x12>\x1e\xf3\xda\xae\xb2>\x8c\xb7k\x8aN2CZX\xe3\xe4\r\x7f\xc6\x80\xba\x13\x13\x90\xa4'
b = bytearray(s)
```

result:

```
b
bytearray(b'\x12>\x1e\xf3\xda\xae\xb2>\x8c\xb7k\x8aN2CZX\xe3\xe4\r\x7f\xc6\x80\xba\x13\x13\x90\xa4')

b[3]
243
```

see: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#bytearray